# ICS and calendar agent causing a lot of requests for past events on my endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, calendar, icalendar, user-agent

I am getting hit with this user agent below on a subscribed calendar day.  This is causing high thread counts to be used.  When looking at these requests, it's for past events that have expired.  How can I stop this from calling my endpoint if events have already pass?

```
macOS/12.1 (21C52) CalendarAgent/961
```

**Example ICS**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT30M
X-WR-CALDESC:World Series-Reno - 16u (Please note that updates can take up
  to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedules.)
X-WR-CALNAME:Snohomish Shock 05 vs Idaho Intensity
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:World Series-Reno - 16u (Please note that updates can take up 
 to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedules.)
DTSTAMP:20220718T160603Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220719T080000
GEO:39.608123;-119.677819
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220705T150600
LOCATION:6400 Vista Blvd. Sparks  Nevada 89436
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Snohomish Shock 05 vs Idaho Intensity
UID:Game-19308557
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Los_Angeles
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

**UPDATED ICS:**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT30M
X-WR-CALDESC:The 2022 West Coast Championship schedule for the Team Inspir
 e National (Girls 9th Level 2)
X-WR-CALNAME:Team Inspire National (Girls 9th Level 2) - 2022 West Coast C
 hampionship
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:2022 West Coast Championship - Girls 9th Level 2 (Please note 
 that updates can take up to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedul
 es.)
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T154500
DTSTAMP:20220819T000250Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T143000
GEO:36.132541;-115.155330
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T204300
LOCATION:3150 Paradise Rd Las Vegas Nevada 89109
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Team Inspire National vs NWBA Futures
UID:Game-19293054
URL:https://test.com/177044/2022-west-coast-championship
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:2022 West Coast Championship - Girls 9th Level 2 (Please note 
 that updates can take up to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedul
 es.)
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T193000
DTSTAMP:20220819T000250Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T181500
GEO:36.132541;-115.155330
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220714T224200
LOCATION:3150 Paradise Rd Las Vegas Nevada 89109
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:CBA U15 Viper vs Team Inspire National
UID:Game-19293055
URL:https://test.com/177044/2022-west-coast-championship
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:2022 West Coast Championship - Girls 9th Level 2 (Please note 
 that updates can take up to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedul
 es.)
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220715T151500
DTSTAMP:20220819T000250Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220715T140000
GEO:36.132541;-115.155330
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220715T193000
LOCATION:3150 Paradise Rd Las Vegas Nevada 89109
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Team Inspire National vs Team Inspire Select
UID:Game-19292017
URL:https://test.com/177044/2022-west-coast-championship
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:2022 West Coast Championship - Girls 9th Level 2 (Please note 
 that updates can take up to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedul
 es.)
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220716T173000
DTSTAMP:20220819T000250Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220716T161500
GEO:36.132541;-115.155330
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220716T202400
LOCATION:3150 Paradise Rd Las Vegas Nevada 89109
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:NWBA Futures vs Team Inspire National
UID:Game-19292022
URL:https://test.com/177044/2022-west-coast-championship
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:2022 West Coast Championship - Girls 9th Level 2 (Please note 
 that updates can take up to 24 hours to fully populate subscribed schedul
 es.)
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220717T140000
DTSTAMP:20220819T000250Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220717T124500
GEO:36.132541;-115.155330
LAST-MODIFIED;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20220717T191300
LOCATION:3150 Paradise Rd Las Vegas Nevada 89109
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:NWBA 15u Silver vs Team Inspire National
UID:Game-19292020
URL:https://test.com/177044/2022-west-coast-championship
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Curious as to what you mean by "getting hit".

Comment: I have an endpoint that serves a ICS file, so I am getting hit every so often to get updates on it to see if changes occurred.

Comment: sounds reasonable...  Did you detect any errors in the datagram?

Comment: Datagram? What?

Comment: Hey @Mike, after going through old  code, there is another important property for each event and that is the UID. UID is the unique key for the associated event. If there is no UID, it could definitely cause an issue.

Comment: Using a UID also grants a feature that allows updates you make to the event to propagate to users with the event already in the calendar.

Comment: After running some of my own performance tests, I am always able to ping expired events. The method I used in the past was to serve a lightweight 404 page with one line of text. No markup. Just text.

Comment: Please let me know how you fare with it. Maybe we can both learn something here. Sorry for all the comments lol

Comment: Are you using a .net handler (ashx) to return the ics file?

Comment: I would have the handler write to the response “bad request” or “event expired” or something. It’s the biggest impact you can make. Calendar programs automatically hide expired events, but don’t delete them. Any user can go back to old events and ping your site. That’s why setting an end time is important. That way the calendar handles expired events before a request is ever sent to your endpoint.

Comment: Basically, events created without an end date may never be hidden from a user’s calendar program, which results in a ping every time they open their calendar.

Comment: Dan you got an email? I think we can do this via that until we find an exact answer you can post and I can award any bounty points.  I know my sample didn't have a END on it, but it did after you commented so I already had that somehow. How does this work, I have the UID? `Using a UID also grants a feature that allows updates you make to the event to propagate to users with the event already in the calendar. `

Comment: @DanMullin these update doesn't seem to be working.  Getting calls all over the place for a July event.

Comment: I didn’t see this until now. Did you send a message to my email? I’ll check for it. When a user is subscribed to an event that has UID, a program like Outlook will use that as a way to check for updates to that specific event

Comment: Think of UIDs as a channel to send push notifications.

Comment: Sorry you never provided the email address unless I missed it.

Comment: I’ve been tinkering with this one for the past month in my own system. Could you include me on another email send? Let me know the subject line. You can email me directly to coordinate.

Comment: How do I even email you? I dont know your email address.

Comment: Just a heads up past events are still getting pinged. You mentioned after two years it will stop. Where did you get that info?